# MVVM Light EventToCommand and Silverlight DataForm - I need the EventArgs and a custom CommandParameter. Possible?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light, dataform, eventtocommand

I have a `DataForm` bound to a collection of RoleViewModel objects.  I'm using MVVMLight's `EventToCommand` behaviour bound to the `EditEnding` event of the `DataForm` to inform my ViewModel when a Role has been edited.

Now,... the user edits a role and can either click 'OK', 'Cancel' or they can simply navigate away. This information is held in the `DataFormEditAction` property in the `DataFormEditEndedEventArgs` (OK being `DataFormEditAction.Commit` and the others being `DataFormEditAction.Cancel`).

The problem is that I have to choose whether I select `PassEventArgsToCommand`, making the signature of the command `RelayCommand<DataFormEditEndedEventArgs>` or I bind the `CurrentItem` of the `DataForm` to the `CommandParameter` of the behaviour, making the signature `RelayCommand<RoleViewModel>`. I'm going to need **both**.

I need the `EventArgs` to know whether the user has cancelled the edit or not and I need the new Role to save it back to the database if they didn't cancel it.

Does anyone have any clever suggestions here?  I guess I could get my hands dirty and create a second behaviour with two parameters but I'd rather not if there's a more elegant solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your viewmodel holds a bindable value of the newrole to the dataform, then you can PassEventArgsToCommand, and you can manipulate data before saving/updating/cancelling.

This is how we have solved a similar scenario.

Comment: I've been waiting for someone to answer this for ages.  This is exactly the approach I took in the end and is, of course, the right way.  Some days everything looks like a nail I guess. :-)